# PTY.spawn prints incorrect output and hangs

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use PTY to run commands from my Ruby program. A very basic example is below:

```
require "pty"


PTY.spawn("wc", "-l") do |r, w, pid|
  w.write("one\ntwo\nthree\n")
  w.close
  while !r.eof?
    begin
      data = r.read_nonblock(1024)
      print(data)
    rescue IO::WaitReadable
      IO.select([r])
    end
  end
end
```

My intention with this code is to run `wc`, write three lines to `wc`'s stdin, and then read the output from PTY's output stream. However, this is what I see as the program output

```
> bundle exec ruby wc_test.rb
one
two
three
```

As you can see, the data written to `w` is read back through `r`, which seems wrong. After the output, the program hangs. If I remove the `print(data)` line, then there is no output from the program, but it still hangs.